# Excel Formula Bar Display

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using a 2003 template, converted to 2013, Here is the problem. I can type a formula in the formula bar. But the cell will not show the value or the formula. when I try in another cell same thing. But when I go back to the original cell, the formula is still there in the formula bar, but again no Value or formula is in the cell. How can I fix this? I have a Spanish keyboard, I have tried the FN key and 2key, ctrl H or replace, reformatted the cell, do not see a circular reference, I am stumped as to what it could be and how to fix it, is there a way to delete and insert new cells

Comment: Check if the cells are formatted as 'Text' - then anything you type is considered text, even if it looks like a formula to you. If this is the case, change the format to 'General', and it should work afterwards.

Comment: If the cell shows *nothing at all*, it might be set to 'White Text on White background' or similar. verify that too.

Answer (score 1):

The way to attack a problem like this is to ask yourself:

*"If I wanted to hide a cell's contents, how would I do it ??"*

This will get you a set of possible problems to investigate!

One way to hide a cells' content is to format the font color the same as the cell background color. Another way is to apply a Custom Format of :

**;;;**

In either case, **clear format** on the bad cell and see what happens.

Comment: Third way can be conditional formatting.

Comment: @MátéJuhász  **Good Catch!!** ......................